# To find an exact match in Solr 3.6.2

Tags: solr

I am using solr 3.6.2. Search passes on the prefix, suffix and the middle of the word.

If I search for `"20%"`, then in the search results is an expression of `"20%"`, `"* 0%"` and `"* 20 *"`. How do I exclude from the search results `"0% *"` and `"* 20 *"` and leave only an exact match `"20%"`? File **schema.xml** below:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
                pattern="[.-_]" replacement=" ">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory">
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false">
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="back">
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front">
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1">
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory">
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory">
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory">
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt">
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true">
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1">
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory">
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Which search handler are you using (such as `/select`)? If you are using a custom one, can you show the entry in your `solrconfig.xml`.

Comment: In my solrconfig.xml:

 requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler"
 lst name="defaults"
       str name="echoParams">explicit</str
       int name="rows">10</int
       str name="df">text</str
     /lst

Comment: Have a go at reformatting the code in your question. The code is currently a bit messed up. Tidier code will help people understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [this information on the WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter) you can see that non-alphanumeric characters are discarded. For example, the string "20%50" will be broken into two tokens "20" and "50".

A [Solr wiki page covering WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) explains how to change this behavior. In summary, the analyzer for your filter will need to change to:

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory">
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- The last parameter to the next filter is new! -->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="myTypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

The parameter `types="myTypes.txt"` specifies a file in which you control how special characters should be interpreted. Your `myTypes.txt` should be in the `solr/conf` directory, and its contents might look like this:

```
% => DIGIT
```

This causes the '%' to be treated as a digit. See the Solr wiki link above for more details.

Comment: Yes! 
    
    <analyzer type="query">

            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>

            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="myTypes.txt"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>